# Dropzonejs + Image Intervention php return value is random html codes

Tags: laravel-5.1, dropzone.js, intervention

My upload code is working good using dropzonejs, and my next task is to create a thumbnail for the image that was uploaded. And so I've used Image Intervention and I was able to create a thumbnail, the only problem I have is when I try to combine the two task in one method, dropzonejs is returning a bunch of html codes. and well, actually everytime I put a return statement in my UploadImage method it returns random html codes. I have read the documentation of dropzonejs and I don't have an idea where the codes coming from. any advice is appreciated. thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

below are my codes.

Route:

```
Route::post('uploadimage', 'ProductController@uploadImage');
```

Controller:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){

       //create folder
        $products = new Products();

        $args['foldername'] = $request->input('folname');

        $products->createDirectory($args);

        $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();



        $request->file('file')->move(public_path().env('FOLDER_NAME_IMAGES').$args['foldername'].'/', $origName );

        $this->createThumbnail($request);

    }

public function createThumbnail($request){

    $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $image = new Image();
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $objImage = $image->make($file->getRealPath());
    //create thumbnail
    $objImage->save(public_path().env('FOLDER_NAME_IMAGES').'fad611c8-56c7-4a7a-8af9-a2908267f08f'.'/'.$origName)
        ->resize(200,200)            // ->greyscale()
        ->save(public_path().env('FOLDER_NAME_IMAGES').'fad611c8-56c7-4a7a-8af9-a2908267f08f'.'/'.'thumb-'.$origName);

}
```

JS code:

```
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
            previewNode.id = "";
            var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
            previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body,
        {
            url: "/uploadimage",
            thumbnailWidth: 80,
            thumbnailHeight: 80,
            parallelUploads: 10,
            previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
            clickable: ".fileinput-button",
            previewsContainer: "#previews",
            maxFiles: 10,
            maxFilesize: 200, //  MB
            acceptedFiles: "image/*"
        });

        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
            // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
            var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;
            formData.append('folname',folname);
        });

        document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
        };

        myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file,xhr,formData) {
            var file_name = file.name; //filename of image

            var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;

            console.log(folname);
            console.log(file_name);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/deleteimage',
                data: { 'filename': file_name,'folname': folname },
                success: function(report) {
                    console.log(report);
                },
                error: function(report) {
                    console.log(report);
                }
            });
        });

        myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            // Hookup the start button
            //get elementbyid set value to previous + 1
            var val_pic_count = document.getElementById('pic_count').value;
            document.getElementById("pic_count").value = Number(val_pic_count) + 1;
        });
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="actions">
        <div class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <span>Add pictures...</span>
        </div>
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <span>Remove all</span>
         </button>
    </div> <!--<div id="actions">-->


    <input type="hidden" name="pic_count" id="pic_count" value="0">
    <span dz-max-files-reached ></span>
    <br><br>
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="previews">
                <div id="template">
                    <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
                    <span class="name" data-dz-name></span>
                    <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <span>Delete</span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
        </li>
         <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
```

Result:

[image]

The *createThumbnail* method is working when i tried it separately.

Comment: okay, the magic of sharing!.. I found something in the random html codes, it says, "Image source not readable".. I will dig into details of this

Comment: I know now what the heck are those html codes, it's the whole laravel return page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the problem.It's the sequence of my methods and most importantly the variable that is being passed to Intervention object is wrong.

so basically the problem is I was trying to save a file that has already been moved.the createThumbnail method should go first before the saving or moving of the original file.

correct code below.

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){

       //create folder
        $products = new Products();

        $args['foldername'] = $request->input('folname');

        $products->createDirectory($args);

        $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

        $this->createThumbnail($request);    

        $request->file('file')->move(public_path().env('FOLDER_NAME_IMAGES').$args['foldername'].'/', $origName );



    }
```

and also I found out that in my createThumbnail method, it's not accepting the value of the getRealPath() method.

previous code:

```
$objImage = $image->make($file->getRealPath());
```

the right way is to just pass the $file variable

correct code:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$objImage = $image->make($file);
```

and also for the random html codes. it's not random, I just missed reading the bottom part of the codes it's basically the html codes of laravel error page. problem solved.